# How to Display Data in Listview.builder based on condition in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have Json response as below.

```
{
  "responseCode": 200,
  "responseMessage": "OK",
  "data": null,
  "dataList": [
    {
      "createdate": "02-04-2022 01:06 PM",
      "updatedate": "15-03-2022 04:40 PM",
      "caseStatus": "In Progress"
    },
    {
      "createdate": "12-03-2022 01:06 PM",
      "updatedate": "15-03-2022 04:40 PM",
      "caseStatus": "Done"
    },
    {
      "createdate": "02-04-2022 01:06 PM",
      "updatedate": "15-03-2022 04:40 PM",
      "caseStatus": "Done"
    },
    {
      "createdate": "12-03-2022 01:06 PM",
      "updatedate": "15-03-2022 04:40 PM",
      "caseStatus": "In Progress"
    }
  ],
  "excelDataList": null,
  "totalRecords": 15,
  "pageRecords": 10,
  "currentPageNumber": 1,
  "totalPages": 2
}
```

So i have to display only those data which date is today,

So how i can do this?

I got the all data in listview but how i can get by conditions?

Comment: Instead of adding condition in you `listView widget`, filter the data list first using `List.where` and then pass it to your `widget`

Comment: Okay Now second, If i want to get record of current week so how i can do?

Answer (score 0):

Just use List.where to filter your data based on any field you want and then pass it your `ListView` widget, for example

Today:

```
updatedate.day == DateTime.now().day
```

Range of date (startDate and endDate should be calculated first based on the requirement):

```
updatedate.isAfter(startDate.day) && updatedate.isBefore(endDate.day)
```